# React Native UI component create ios ui controller

Tags: ios, react-native

I need to create a ios uiviewcontroller to implement a delegate and returned to react native make a native ui components.
I already read official document [Native UI Components ios](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios)

but i still don't understand how to create a native ui components
can any one known how to create native ui component step by step
thanks